# Search-ADAccount - This operation returned because the timeout period expired

Tags: powershell, active-directory, timeout

I have the following code:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan "90" -ResultPageSize:100 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    where {$_.samaccountname.StartsWith("X") -or $_.samaccountname.StartsWith("Y")} |
    Select-Object samaccountname,Name,AccountExpirationDate |
    Export-Csv $PSScriptRoot\Results\AD_Expiration_Dates_Accounts_Next_90_days_$((Get-Date).ToString('dd_MM_yyyy')).csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

I keep getting the error mentioned in the title with or without the `-ResultPageSize:` option.

The interesting thing is that when I change the `-TimeSpan` value I get more or less values and the data seems therefore to be coherent but, it always ends with the same error nevertheless.

The thing is, I'm not sure I can trust these values; even when I remove the option `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` I don't get any other error or information.

Does anyone have any input on this?

Comment: Is your goal to find *ADUser* accounts that are expiring within 90 days? If so, why not use the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet?

Comment: hey darth, how many users do you have in the OU/domain you are searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance, it'd be way better to use `Get-ADUser` with a proper filter for all the criteria you want, rather than returning a whole lot of results and then using a `where` clause on them.

Also consider using the `-searchbase` option to limit which OU you search (if all the target accounts are in a specific OU).

```
$now = get-date
$90days = (get-date).adddays(90)
get-aduser -filter '(AccountExpirationDate -gt $now) -and (AccountExpirationDate -le $90days) -and (samAccountName -like "X*" -or sAMAccountName -like "Y*" )' -properties AccountExpirationDate 
| Select-Object samaccountname,Name,AccountExpirationDate
```

Comment: Perfection, it works! Thank you very much. I had used the `Get-ADUser` approach but it was painfully slow. The thing was I was using `Where` instead of `-like`.